# Cocoa check if function exists

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'd like to use a function that's only available on OS X 10.9, but WITHOUT compiling with the 10.9 SDK. Is that possible?

I've tried weak linking, but the compiler just gives out an error that the function is not defined.

Comment: Wait - is this a function or a method. The two are very different.

Comment: It's a C Function (AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions) which is only available on 10.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a C function, you can do this with the `dlopen` function:

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void *lib = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices", RTLD_LAZY);
    void *function = dlsym(lib, "CGColorGetConstantColor");

    // cast the function to the right format
    CGColorRef (*dynamic_getConstantColor)(CFStringRef colorName) = function;

    NSLog(@"%@", dynamic_getConstantColor(CFSTR("kCGColorBlack")));

    dlclose(lib);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-06-20 12:43:13.510 TestProj[1699:303]  [ (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Profile)] ( 0 1 )
```

You will need to figure out the dylib in which the function you want resides, first, though.

This *will* break the sandbox limitations on iOS, and Mac most likely as well. It is the price you pay for trying to get around the linker.

Comment: Any idea where I could find the dylib for /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frame‌​works/HIServices.framework/Versions/Current/HIServices ?

Comment: @bogdansrc yup, updated my answer with a symbol from a framework.

Comment: The output "Hello World, from dynamic!" is not consistent with the code anymore, which might confuse future readers :-)

Answer (score 4):

You say you don't want to compile against 10.9, but give no reason. Just in case you *can*:

If you set your target to 10.9 and your deployment to something lower then Xcode will weak link the 10.9 frameworks. You can then test for a C function being available by comparing its name to `NULL`. This fragment is taken from [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html):

```
extern int MyWeakLinkedFunction() __attribute__((weak_import));

int main()
{
   int result = 0;

   if (MyWeakLinkedFunction != NULL)
   {
      result = MyWeakLinkedFunction();
   }

   return result;
}
```

(BTW: no sandbox issues this way.)

Comment: Great comment, still works in 2020 in a Bridging header to be used in Swift :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with Objective-C methods, maybe you could do it with selectors.. 
So first check if the selector is available with:

```
[object respondsToSelector:@selector(osxMavericksFun)]
```

And if this test is correct try firing the Method via selectors

```
[object performSelector:@selector(osxMavericksFun)];
```

If you want to call c functions there is no way to do this.

Comment: This question is about functions, not methods.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to call if it would be available?

Comment: There is no way to do this.. You will need to build on 10.9 to use a c function of 10.9

Comment: @lukaswelte actually, using dlopen/dlsym you can do that, if you want to.

Comment: Doesn't this break the OS X Sandbox restrictions?

Comment: @lukaswelte I'm not sure. I know it does on iOS, but Mac *is* different in many respects.

Comment: The app I am using this in is not sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
if (AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions != NULL){
    NSDictionary *options = @{(__bridge id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
    accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
}else{
    accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrusted();
}
```

This method is described in [apple's documentation Listing 3-2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6). It is much simpler than the method described by Richard J. Ross III which you accepted as correct.