# How do I correctly declare and use NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Following an answer I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18121292/1701170, I have the following code:

```
bool accessibilityEnabled = false;

// Check and make sure assistive devices is enabled.
if (AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions != NULL) {
    // 10.9 and later
    NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
    accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
} else {
    // 10.8 and older
    if (AXAPIEnabled() == true) {
        accessibilityEnabled = true;
    }
}

if (accessibilityEnabled) {
    // do something
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
[apply] error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSDictionary'; did you mean 'UseDictionary'?
[apply]         NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
[apply]         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
[apply]         UseDictionary
```

Do I have to import NSDictionary?

The imports at the top of the file are as follows:

```
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <sys/time.h>

 #include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

 #include "NativeErrors.h"
 #include "NativeGlobals.h"
 #include "NativeHelpers.h"
 #include "NativeThread.h"
 #include "NativeToJava.h"
 #include "OSXInputHelpers.h"
```

This is my first time looking at Objective-C.

Comment: What template did you create this project from? Did you link Foundation? And is it imported properly?

Comment: Also, don't put tag in your titles, thanks

Comment: This is from https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/  I am looking at src/native/osx/NativeThread.c, around line 665

Answer (score 3):

The project you linked looks like a plain C project to me. NSDictionary is an Objective-C class and part of the Foundation framework from Apple. You have to link Foundation.framework and make sure it is imported in your source. If you're just experimenting, your best bet would probably be to just create a new project in Xcode using the Command Line Tool (of type Foundation) template.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm probably in over my head.  The project I linked to won't complile on OS X 10.9 and I'm trying to put in a simple patch, but I may not understand the context well enough.