# Detect if user is typing in macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos

In macos I have the following code to detect if the user is typing (literally if the user is typing any key):

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDown
                                       handler:^(NSEvent *event){
                                           NSLog(@"keydown: %@", event.characters);

                                       }];
```

This code absolutely does not work. Is there an alternative to NSKeyDown for global monitor?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does your code reach this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496336/addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchingmask-not-working)

Comment: thanks guys you are right I had a duplicate function. I had NSKeyDown and I had another NSEvent global monitor functions with NSRightMouseUp. But what if I want to run both at the same time? Can I run both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using NSEventMaskKeyDown, not NSKeyDown.

So this should work

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSEventMaskKeyDown | NSEventMaskRightMouseUp
                                       handler:^(NSEvent *event){
                                           NSLog(@"keydown: %@", event.characters);

                                       }];
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however it should be NSRightMouseUp not  NSEventMaskRightMouseUp