# Programmatically controlling accessibility options in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, accessibility

In Mac OSX, is there any API for controlling accessibility options such as "Zoom" and "Invert Display Colors"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Accessibility Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078

You might want to review this question to see if it helps: [Enable access for assistive devices programmatically on 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693408/enable-access-for-assistive-devices-programmatically-on-10-9)