# AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions doesn't return true even when the app is ticked in accessibility

Tags: macos, qt, accessibility

As this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693408/enable-access-for-assistive-devices-programmatically-on-10-9) answered, I use AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions with no option to test if my app has been enabled in the accessibility panel. If not, prompt the window to let users to enable it. There is button bound to this test call as well, so users don't need to close the UI and reopen it.

But sometimes, even after a user enables the app, AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions still returns false. When I check the sqlite database, it shows my app as "kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.abc.def|0|1|1||". The first 1 digit indicates it has been allowed apparently. But the api call still returns false. At this point, if I close the UI, the app is unticked in the accessibility panel which causes a loop so users can never pass this step.

Another thing is this app is actually a version 2 of the previous app. But the user did replace the bundle with the v2 one. Not sure if this is related.

Any idea why this would happen?

```
NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @NO};
BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (!accessibilityEnabled) {
    NSString *urlString = @"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility";
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}
```

Comment: It worked for me after toggling the app off and on again in system preferences

Answer (score 9):

Update: In Xcode, Signing & Capabilities, make sure you have selected a Team and Signing Certificate.

Original answer:

I experienced this when developing an app on macOS 10.14.5 in Xcode trying both `AXIsProcessTrusted` and `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` .

After wasting a lot of time trying all sorts of things, including different options for `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions`, logging out/in, rebooting, praying, and crying, I eventually shut down my machine and powered it back on in frustration. Then it worked. Hopefully nobody else has this same experience.